# Elasticsearch Shape query to find the bounding polygon and background color from Nested JSON (Google OCR response)

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a response from an OCR application which is a JSON similar to Google Vision OCR response. I want to put this in Elasticsearch in order to perform a shape query. Although I am able to put the JSON in Elasticsearch, I am not able to come up with a perfect `schema` and `mapping` to perform a search on the basis of the shape or the `boundingPoly` and the `bgColor`.

I am pretty new to **Elasticsearch** and I have few questions.

**(1)** How can I perform search on the basis of the `boundingPoly` and `bgColor`?

**(2)** Do I need to change the schema for performing the search or can I keep it as it is? What the best schema and mapping that suits my purpose?

**(3)** Also, I would like to perform a search on the basis of `bgColor`. How can I achieve this?

> I tried with [Geo-shape query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) but failed to implement it with the proper result. Also, there is a restriction in `Geo-shape query` that the values must lie between 90 - 180. I think that part we can handle by normalizing the values.

*Sample JSON:*

```
{
    "responses": [{
        "textAnnotations": [{
                "description": "were",
                "boundingPoly": {
                    "vertices": [{
                            "x": 112,
                            "y": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 333,
                            "y": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 333,
                            "y": 93
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 112,
                            "y": 93
                        }
                    ],
                    "confidence": 99
                },
                "wordInfo": {
                    "length": 4,
                    "width": 221,
                    "height": 88,
                    "bgColor": [
                        255,
                        255,
                        251
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "description": "gonna",
                "boundingPoly": {
                    "vertices": [{
                            "x": 338,
                            "y": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 589,
                            "y": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 589,
                            "y": 93
                        },
                        {
                            "x": 338,
                            "y": 93
                        }
                    ],
                    "confidence": 99
                },
                "wordInfo": {
                    "length": 5,
                    "width": 251,
                    "height": 88,
                    "bgColor": [
                        255,
                        255,
                        255
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using bounding box coordinates of words over an image i would suggest you to use [shape](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shape.html) datatype as there is not limitation of coordinate values.

```
"vertices": {
            "type": "shape"
        }
```

Also make sure to manipulate the bounding box coordinates in below format.

```
[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4],[x1,y1]]
```

You might want to change the schema in elasticsearch as it will be easier for you to search different fields in a document.

Post data into document like:

```
POST /example/_doc
{
    "vertices" : {
    "type" : "polygon",
    "coordinates" : [
        [ [1000.0, -1001.0], [1001.0, -1001.0], [1001.0, -1000.0], [1000.0, -1000.0], [1000.0, -1001.0] ]
    ]
  }
}
```

For Searching you can use make use of [envelope](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-shape-query.html) type query so you wouldn't have to write all the coordinates of bounding box, you can set a envelope(rectangle) to be searched in  and it will give you all the documents that are contained in the envelope. 
Note : coordinate input for envelope type searching in a bit different it takes `[[minX,maxY],[maxX,minY]]` this type of format.

Example:

```
{
  "query":{
      "bool": {
          "must": {
              "match_all": {}
          },
          "filter": {
              "shape": {
                  "prefix.vertices": {
                      "shape": {
                          "type": "envelope",
                          "coordinates": [
                                  [40,60],
                                  [100,40]
                              ]
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

As each field in elasticsearch can have single or multiple(in form of array) values, bgColor can be searched using must-match query for matching all the values to bgColor elements.

Example:

```
{
  "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match": {"prefix.wordInfo.bgColor": 1}},
            {"match": {"prefix.wordInfo.bgColor": 2}},
            {"match": {"prefix.wordInfo.bgColor": 3}}
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`geo_shape` is intended for ... geographic shapes. So you'll have to either

- normalize your coordinates so that they fit into the lat/long spec limits and only then sync them as such
- or you can treat them as being in the, say, Mercator (EPSG:900913) projection which supports values like [589, 93] and then convert them to actual lat/longs. Though you should keep in mind that, say, the geopoint [0 (lon), 1 (lat)] converted to mercator coords is [0, ~111325]. So you'll also need some scaling factor in order to not make your geopolygon too small. In other words, a difference of 1 mercator coordinate is [0.000009°](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=3857&t_srs=4326&x=0.0000000&y=1.0000000) in WGS 84 which means that your polygons could be too small to index and/or too high-res to [effectively store](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#geoshape-indexing-approach).

---

Step-by-step guide:

1. Convert and/or normalize your coordinates
2. Convert your [x,y] pairs into [lon, lat] pairs
3. Convert your [r,g,b] colors into rgb strings ([0,0,0] => "#000000") -- unless you intend to query by the actual r,g,b channels
4. Create an index w/ a geoshape mapping:

```
PUT /example
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "geo_shape"
            },
            "bgColor": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

5. Make sure your polygon coordinates start and end with the same geopoint & wrap them in 2 more empty arrays to comply with the geojson standard.
6. Sync your polygons + `bgColor`s

```
POST /example/_doc
{
    "location" : {
        "type" : "polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
        ]
    },
    "bgColor": "#000000"
}
```

After that there's plenty of resources already answered elsewhere as to how polygons are searched and how to search (color) strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this out!